# `None` when trying to access parameter gradients in PyTorch Lightning

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I want to perform some operations on the gradients while using Pytorch Lightning. I know that the model weights are getting updated (weights change every step, and loss decreases).

I added the following function to my `pl.LightningModule` to capture the gradients:

```py
def on_after_backward(self):
        for p in self.parameters():
            print(p.grad)
        norms = {n: torch.norm(p.grad) for n, p in self.named_parameters()}
        self.log_dict(norms)
```

However, I always get `None` as the gradients here.

How do I capture the gradients of this module before the optimizer step?

### EDIT

For debugging purposes, I turned off automatic optimization, calling `backward` manually.

`training_step` code:

```py
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        if self.trainer.is_global_zero:
            print()
            print("################")
            print(list(self.parameters())[-1].grad)
        args = self.args
        opt = self.optimizers()
        opt.zero_grad()
        idx, targets = batch
        logits = self(idx)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(logits.view(-1, logits.size(-1)), targets.view(-1))
        loss = L2Wrap.apply(loss, logits)
        self.manual_backward(loss)
        if self.trainer.is_global_zero:
            print(list(self.parameters())[-1].grad)
            print("################")
            print()
        opt.step()
        return loss
```

Weights change before and after `opt.step()`; gradientts are `None` both times.

Comment: This seems to be the correct way to get the gradient. How does your `trianing_step` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deepspeed partitions the gradient across devices, and to access it the function `deepspeed.utils.safe_get_full_grad` needs to be called. Try:

```
grad_data = deepspeed.utils.safe_get_full_grad(param)
```

[See the full docs here](https://deepspeed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/zero3.html#deepspeed.utils.safe_get_full_grad).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue: I was using DeepSpeed. Replacing it with standard DDP gives the required gradients using the hook.

If anyone knows how to get gradients when using DeepSpeed, please reply as well.